# What is sideport memory?

Tags: video

What is sideport memory and how do I enable/use it?

My new motherboard claims:

- Equipped 1 Gigabit (128MB) DDR3 1333MHz IGP boost memory to accelerate onboard VGA 3D performance enhanced up to an additional 15%.
- Independent IGP memory can reduce the consumption of system memory

but I don't know how, or even if, I can take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used automatically by the video hardware.

Quoted from this [thread](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/showthread.php?t=19172):

> Sideport memory is basically what ATI
>   calls the dedicated frame buffer
>   memory for the integrated graphics
>   chip, in this case with the tx2500z,
>   there is 64MB of local memory
>   dedicated to graphics.
>
> Sideport memory is runs considerably
>   faster than system memory, therefore
>   providing noticeable increases in
>   performance over standard IGPs which
>   constantly accesses system memory.
>
> The main reason for the frame buffer
>   is that the IGP need not have to
>   access the memory controller which in
>   AMD systems is located in the CPU to
>   access the memory. In earlier
>   platforms this used to wake the CPU up
>   from low power state just to refresh
>   the buffer. That's why in Griffin the
>   memory controller has its own separate
>   power plane, so even if the IGP needs
>   to refresh it doesn't need to access
>   the CPU at all (if it has sideport
>   memory) or if necessary just uses the
>   memory controller to access the RAM
>   not waking up the CPU cores from their
>   low power state.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/790gx-graphics-sideport,2088.html

Comment: Unusually for Tom's Hardware, this article didn't actually answer either of my questions.